# where are my bitcoins

Tags: money

I downloaded program some months ago. I always wait for blocks to sync before I do anything. After everything is synced I have been going to where the surveys are to get coins, however, after completely finishing survey, nothing ever shows up. I must have done in excess of 15 surveys and still nothing. I've tried using new addresses and old addresses to no avail. I have contacted support and they always come back saying that the coins have been sent. I have checked and verified everything that is possible and still nothing.  What in the world am I doing wrong?

Comment: "I have checked and verified everything that is possible and still nothing." Can you explain what you checked? Have you verified that they are actually sending bitcoins? Ask them to provide the 64 digit transaction ID.

Answer (score 1):

Go to this website: http://blockchain.info/

In the search in the top-right corner, type in the address that you sent to the survery people.  (Addresses are not secret, you don't have to worry about giving it to the website.)

If they sent you bitcoins, you should be able to see the transaction.

If you see the words "Firstbits not found" in red then it means that the address has not received any coins yet.